# Нужен совет по реализации алгоритма

Tags: javascript

Привет. Пишу веб-приложение, которое обращается к API, получает JSON, обрабатывает и выводит на экран полученные данные. Но сейчас я встретился с проблемой. Во время прохода циклом по массиву и `.push()` большого объёма данных происходит подлагивание страницы. Заметно это по тому, что дёргается лоадер во время операции. Можно ли как-то вынести выполнение определённого набора функций в отдельный фоновый процесс, чтобы ресурсы, затрачиваемые на какую-то операцию не вызывали дёрганий/рывков/подтормаживаний в основном потоке(где крутятся лоадеры, авто-инкрементируется progress-bar и все остальное. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать Web Workers.

Минимальный необходимый пример решения:

```
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Будет сделано, босс.

Comment: А как на счёт [Multithread.js](https://keithwhor.github.io/multithread.js/)? Не одно и тоже ли это?

Comment: Multithread - простая оболочка, которая устраняет трудности с работой с Web Workers и передаваемыми объектами.